Im New To JPA and Hibernate I would like to know if this is an acceptable way of Fetching Data using JPA
There are three types of users

users with ROLE_User
users with ROLE_Admin
users with ROLE_User and ROLE_Admin

I wrote a query that filters out all users with admin access
in MySQL
SELECT * 
FROM users u 
WHERE u.id NOT IN (
    SELECT u.id 
    FROM users u 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users_authorities ua
    ON u.id = ua.id_users 
    WHERE ua.id_authorities IN(
        SELECT a.id FROM authorities a WHERE a.authority = "ROLE_Admin"
    )
);

In JPA
TypedQuery<Person> query =  entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p " +
"WHERE p NOT IN (SELECT ps FROM Person ps " +
"JOIN  ps.authorities a " +
"WHERE a IN (SELECT au FROM Authorities au WHERE au.authority = \"ROLE_Admin\"))" ,Person.class);

the results are the same but I would like to know if there are better alternatives for the JPA query
